# I can't write a Spark DataFrame to database with jdbc

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, dataframe

i am attempting to write a simple dataframe into oracle database but I get an error message. I use a case class and a list to construct my dataframe. I found that that we can use a method jdbc after a write to insert data to my oracle database. 
I tried this code:

```
case class MyClass(A: String, B: Int)
val MyClass_List = List(MyClass("att1", 1), MyClass("att2", 2))

val MyClass_df = MyClass_List.toDF()

MyClass_df.write
            .mode("append")
            .jdbc(url, tableTest, prop)
```

but I get the following error:

```
17/07/12 14:57:04 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1499864218000 ms.0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:426)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:446)
        at Test$$anonfun$1.apply(Test.scala:177)
        at Test$$anonfun$1.apply(Test.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:426)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:446)
        at Test$$anonfun$1.apply(Test.scala:177)
        at Test$$anonfun$1.apply(Test.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:254)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

i use spark version 2.1.0 and my database as two column A and B respectively typed as varchar and number.

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I was using the driver of mysql despite the driver of oracle.
I should use

```
prop.setProperty("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
```

and not

```
prop.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" as the one in the driver package is deprecated.

```
prop.setProperty("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
```

Comment: @a.moussa . can you please check this and provide solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151363/not-able-to-write-spark-dataset-to-database-using-jdbc